# kendo ui angular2 grid - how to apply class to a grid row

Tags: angular, telerik, telerik-grid

How can I apply a css class to a grid row (TR) based on some condition?

I know I can apply class to a column but not to a whole TR.

Comment: What have you tried so far, this isn't a code writing service. Little/no effort has went in to [asking this question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What is the conditional logic? Where/when do you apply the logic? Here is an example of how to change row color based on data using [`rowTemplate`](http://www.telerik.com/forums/conditionally-changing-the-row-color).

Comment: I know it is not writing service here. You should also at least try to understand what I'm asking and not starting a flame discussion here. The question is very simple and the `condition` is irrelevant here. So: How to apply a css class to a row in a Telerik Angular Grid?

Comment: To which I provided an example, with the best attempt at guessing what you are trying to do based on your 2 line question. The condition _is_ relevant as there may be different approaches to a solution based on where the logic is being applied (inside `dataBound`/`dataBinding`/`edit`/`change` grid event functions, outside the scope of the grid) etc. Therefore I am flagging the question as to be closed as to broad until there is "_enough detail to identify an adequate answer_".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first,use rowClass to generate needed class in row based on row data.(row class callback function)
second,use css to style row(may bee /deep/ grammer is needed with ViewEncapastion.Emulated).
     .k-gird /deep/ tr.xxx

Comment: That's what I was exactly looking for. See http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#toc-rowclass

Answer (score 3):

Since I have just gone through the same scenario, I will show what I've done.  In the grid, set up a function to call from the `rowClass` property

```
<kendo-grid
       [rowClass]="rowCallback"
       >
```

In the component, we create the method/function to evaluate `boolean` values:

```
public rowCallback(context: RowClassArgs) {
    return {
      amber: context.dataItem.isRowAmber,
      red: context.dataItem.isRowRed || context.dataItem.isSpentGreaterThanReceived
    };
  }
```

In the `css` file, I have two styles:

```
.k-grid tr.amber { background-color: #ee840a71;  }
.k-grid tr.red { background-color: #af332a7c; }
```

You can see in the `rowCallback` function that the `context.dataItem`, exposes the data for the row, and the expression can be evaluated in here, thus setting the relevant style.

Comment: I had to add :host ::ng-deep in front of .k-grid tr.amber to make it work.